# Can a mobile number ring if the person has not inserted their simcard into their phone?

Tags: authentication

I dialled a cell phone number and it rang but with no reply. I asked the person later why they did not answer and they said the Sim card was not in the phone. In fact, it was in a purse.... Is this possible? Can a Sim card that is not in a mobile ring?

Comment: It's possible that the person setup [call forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_forwarding) prior to removing the card from the phone. That's a subscription based network setting so it would be persistent regardless if the number called is unreachable. Network operator might choose (or is obliged to, depending on local laws and regulations) or not to notify a caller that the call is being redirected. If this notification was not in effect or you didn't pay attention to it, and nobody could (or wanted to) answer at the redirected number, this what you describe is entirely plausible.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a security question.

But anyway I think your person lied to you. Everyone knows the voice telling something like `The person you have called is temporary not available`. If a cellphone has no contact to the network or is switched of or the sim is not in the cellphone you get either this message or the mailbox.

Comment: Well, sorry about that...

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance it may 'ring', but just for a couple seconds and you should get redirected to the mobile provider's voicemail service or something like that.

A SIM card that is not inserted into a phone would not register on the mobile network and thus not ring.